# Android - Cannot open browser Intent from the url string

Tags: android, android-intent, android-browser, intentservice

I am pasring XML and collecting URL as a string variable. I get the link correct and I can set it in LogCat.

However, when I set up onItemClickListener; it doesn't recognise link and throws ActivityNotFoundException.

Here is the code.

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    final String announcementsTitle="announcements";
    final String announcementsLink = "link";

    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> announcementsList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

    try
    {

        URL url = new URL("http://www.myexperiment.org/announcements.xml?num=100&order=reverse");

        DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();

        Document doc = db.parse(new InputSource(url.openStream()));
        doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();

        NodeList nodeList1 = doc.getElementsByTagName("announcement");


        for(int i=0; i < nodeList1.getLength(); i++)
        {
            //Creating HashMap
            HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

            Node node = nodeList1.item(i);

            //For the announcement title
            Element firstElement = (Element) node;
            NodeList nameList = firstElement.getElementsByTagName("announcement");

            Element nameElement = (Element) nameList.item(0);
            nameList = nameElement.getChildNodes();

            String link1 = firstElement.getAttributeNode("resource").getNodeValue();


            //Adding values of each into HashMap
            map.put(announcementsTitle,((Node) nameList.item(0)).getNodeValue());
            map.put(announcementsLink,link1);

            String title = nameList.item(0).getNodeValue();


            Log.d("Announcements: ", title);
            Log.d("Link: ", link1);

            //Adding HashList to ArrayList
            announcementsList.add(map);

        }//for

        ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, announcementsList,R.layout.announcements,
                                 new String[] {announcementsTitle, announcementsLink}, 
                                 new int[] {R.id.announcementTitle});
        setListAdapter(adapter);

        ListView lv = getListView();

        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener()
        {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) 
            {

                //String the new Intent open the browser with link
                Log.d("Link: ", announcementsLink);

                final Intent announcementsIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(announcementsLink));
                startActivity(announcementsIntent);
            }

        });

    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        System.out.println("XML Parsing Exeption = " + e);
    }

}//onCreate
```

Here is the message from LogCat

```
02-20 22:15:43.203: D/Link:(919): http://www.myexperiment.org/announcements/2  
02-20 22:15:43.203: D/Announcements:(919): New announcements feature!  
02-20 22:15:43.203: D/Link:(919): http://www.myexperiment.org/announcements/1  
02-20 22:15:50.163: D/Link:(919): link  
02-20 22:15:50.243: D/AndroidRuntime(919): Shutting down VM  
02-20 22:15:50.243: W/dalvikvm(919): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40015560)  
02-20 22:15:50.313: E/AndroidRuntime(919): FATAL EXCEPTION: main  
02-20 22:15:50.313: E/AndroidRuntime(919): android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=link }  
02-20 22:15:50.313: E/AndroidRuntime(919):  at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1409)  
02-20 22:15:50.313: E/AndroidRuntime(919):  at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1379)  
02-20 22:15:50.313: E/AndroidRuntime(919):  at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:2827)  
02-20 22:15:50.313: E/AndroidRuntime(919):  at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:2933)
```

Answer (score 0):

You're passing the value of the `announcementsLink` variable to the startActivity as your URI. The value of this variable is and always will be `"link"`. This is not a valid URI. I'm guessing what you wanted to do instead was get the URI associated with the ListItem the clicked on, which you're not doing. You can get the link you stored for a particular list item like so:

```
lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener()
{
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) 
    {
        final String itemLink = adapter.getItem(potition).get(announcementsLink)
        final Intent announcementsIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(itemLink));
        startActivity(announcementsIntent);
    }
});
```

Disclaimer, I haven't tested this code myself, but the general idea is there.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I made the changes you suggested which logically make sense. However, there is an error showing up. It says **itemLink** has to be final, which is. But then it asks **announcementsLink** to be final as well; if I make that final then it throws error to make itemLink just string and not final string.

Comment: Try moving announcementsLinks and announcmentTitles out of the onCreate method. Just make them private static final variables in your class.